# Can removing reference to Passkit will allow me to transfer App from One Developer Account to another Developer account?

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit, app-transfer

I am not able to transfer my iOS App from one Developer Account to another as it contains reference to `PassKit.framework`. Will it be possible to transfer app if I remove `PassKit.framework`.

My app does not contain Wallet entitlement of any kind.